# Bash Issue: AWK

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I came back to work from a break to see that my Bash script wasn't working like it used to. The below tid-bit of code would grab and filter what's in a file. Here's the contents of said file:

```
# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
OEM:/software/oracle/agent/agent12c/core/12.1.0.3.0:N
*:/software/oracle/agent/agent11g:N
dev068:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y

dev299:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y

xtst036:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y

xtst161:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
dev360:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev361:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
xtst215:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
xtst216:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev298:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.03:Y
xtst160:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.03:Y
```

What the code used to produce and throw into an array:

```
dev068
dev299
xtst036
xtst161
dev360
dev361
xtst215
xtst216
dev298
xtst160
```

It would look at the file (oratab), find the database names (e.g. xtst160), and put them into an array. I then used this array for other tasks later in the script. Here's the relevant Bash script code:

```
# Collect the databases using a mixture of AWK and regex, and throw it into an array.
printf "\n2) Collecting databases on %s:\n" $HOSTNAME
declare -a arr_dbs=(`awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora' '$2 ~ key{print $ddma_input}' /etc/oratab`)

# Loop through and print the array of databases.
for i in ${arr_dbs[@]}
do
        printf "%s  " $i
done
```

It doesn't seem anyone has modified the code or that the oratab file format has changed. So I'm not 100% sure what's going on now. Instead of grabbing the few characters, it's grabbing the entire line:

```
dev068:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
```

I'm trying to understand Bash and regex more but I'm stumped. Definitely not my forte. **A broken down explanation of the awk line would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: `ddma_input` is a variable that is unset in your awk script, so it is coerced to `0`, so you end up with `print $0` which prints the whole line.

Comment: @TomFenech Well, I don't think you're wrong. I'm doing a `printf "%s" $ddma_input` before the declare line, and it's not printing anything. However at the beginning of the script, when I have `ddma_input = $1`, I'll echo/print it and it says the correct input. 
Completely strange. Not sure how it's being nulled/changed as it's not being used anywhere else aside from a few functions where it's being called (`$ddma_input`) and not assigned.

Comment: if you want to use a shell variable in an awk script then you need to pass it to the script using `-v` as you are already doing with `key`. I don't see how this was ever working.

Comment: Understandable! It's fairly janky. I found the error. We changed the amount of arguments being passed in and the order they are received. Oops...
Thank you for your time, @TomFenech!

Comment: @Erik, if this was resolved in a manner unlikely to help others, consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. We changed the amount of arguments being passed in and the order they are received.

Answer (score 0):

printing $1 instead $ddma_input and resolve the issue as well.

```
declare -a arr_dbs=(`awk -F ":" -v key='/software/oracle/ora' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab`)

# Loop through and print the array of databases.
for i in ${arr_dbs[@]}
do
        printf "%s  " $i
done
```

Comment: This is still buggy on several regards. `arr=( $(...) )` is, generally speaking, an antipattern: Both IFS-splitting and glob expansion are active, making far more error-prone than using `readarray`, `mapfile`, or `read -a` to populate your array.

Comment: ...and `for i in ${arr[@]}` without the quotes has all the same bugs as `for i in ${arr[*]}`; it needs to be `for i in "${arr[@]}"` to avoid doing its own string-splitting and glob expansion. Likewise, the `$i` in the printf should be `"$i"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement this whole thing in native bash with no external tools at all:

```
arr_dbs=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    "#"*)                        continue ;;
    *:/software/oracle/ora*:*)   arr_dbs+=( "${line%%:*}" ) ;;
  esac
done </etc/oratab

printf '  %s\n' "${arr_dbs[@]}"
```

---

This actually avoids some bugs you had in your original implementation. Let's say you had a line like the following:

```
*:/software/oracle/ora-default:Y
```

If you aren't careful with how you handle that `*`, it'll be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory by the shell whenever expansion occurs.

What does "whenever expansion occurs" mean in this context? Well:

```
# this will expand a * into a list of filenames during the assignment to the array
arr=( $(echo "*") )    # vs the correct read -a arr < <(echo "*")

# this will expand a * into a list of filenames while generating items to iterate over
for i in ${arr[@]}     # vs the correct for i in "${arr[@]}"

# this will expand a * into a list of filenames while building the argument list for echo
i="*"
echo $i                # vs the correct printf '%s\n' "$i"
```

Note the use of `printf` over `echo` -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX specification of `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html).